Postman: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000 when using custom hosts
I  have a request that used to work a while back using postman, but not anymore (I have not changed any settings). The same request works in google chrome.
In postman, the request:
GET {{apiHost}} 
where apiHost is an environment scope variable
Resolves to:
curl --location 'web-api.somedomain.local:8000' 
And the response is
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000 
In chrome, the same URL:
web-api.somedomain.local:8000, gets a response OK
Please note the following section of my /etc/hosts/ file. (on mac), I can not change the hosts file due to job specific reasons, similarly, i can not change apiHosts to 127.0.0.1 , while the connection wont be refused but this is important in the app logic.

127.0.0.1 web-api.somedomain.local

::1 web-api.somedomain.local


Platform details:
Version 11.6.2
UI version
11.6.2-ui-240731-0006
Desktop platform version
11.6.1
Architecture
arm64
OS platform
OS X 23.6.0
If any more details are missing, let me know and I will be happy to provide
I have tried switching off/on proxy settings in postman settings, in addition to enabling /disabling ssl, and specifying HTTP protocol. None of these worked.

Is your webapp listening on ::1 too?

@Botje, no, I want to enforce postman to use IPV4

.. Why? You (or whoever set up your computer) clearly meant for that hostname to resolve to the ipv6 local host ip.

Frankly, I am not sure about the why, I can confirm that the app locally runs on ipv4 but not ipv6, perhaps it is some sort of future proofing thing, or an error, or even a devops feature. Is there a way to force postman to resolve to use ipv4?

Not that I could find. Fix your app to listen on both protocols or run a stupid proxy from the ipv6 localhost to ipv4.
